# kinect's the world coordinate

Tags: ros, world, coordinate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

kinect 3D point has the world coordinate (x,y,z).

where is the the origin of the world coordinates(0,0,0)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38646/kinect%27s-the-world-coordinate/) by [hahaha](https://answers.ros.org/users/2764/hahaha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-12

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hahaha](https://answers.ros.org/users/2764/hahaha/) on 2012-07-12**:
I don't understanding your comment. Could you teach me again in detail ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `frame_id` in the `PointCloud2` header names the relevant `tf` frame of reference.

ROS handles transforms between coordinate frames using the [tf](http://ros.org/wiki/tf) package. That component is complex, not easily summarized here. Please consult the [tf design documentation](http://ros.org/wiki/tf/Design) and the [tf tutorials](http://ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials) for more information.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3